# Ifstream not reading entire text file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm trying to read a text file with `ifstream` and write it to another text file. But either the input text file is read partially, or is written partially to the output file. Only a handful of characters appear in the output text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string in_string;

  ifstream in_stream("test.txt");
  ofstream out_stream("test2.txt");

  while(getline(in_stream, in_string))
  {
   out_stream << in_string;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the input file:

[image: Input]

This is the output file:

[image: Output]

As you can see, only the first few characters are outputted. Is reading the problem, or is writing the problem?

Comment: You **will** be missing some characters in `out_stream` (the newlines) - but that looks like you only get the first "line". Are you using Windows? Perhaps adding `std::ios::binary` when you open both files will help. If you want a copy of the file, there are better ways (using `std::copy` with `std::istreambuf_iterator`s or `std::filesystem::copy_file` for example).

Comment: @Blastfurnace It's a text file of a jpeg hex dump. And the std::getline stopped before it encountered any newline from what I've checked.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I'll try out the std::ios::binary. And yes it's Windows.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot. It worked. Do you know what was the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: @JanglunGuang I suspect it's the Windows line endings in text files that confused `std::getline`. It wouldn't have been a problem on a Linux system for example (because there all files are treated equally, binary or text doesn't matter).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see, another reason to use Linux haha. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @JanglunGuang it is not a "text file of a jpeg hex dump". It is an actual jpeg file.

Comment: @JanglunGuang this is not a Windows vs Linux issue. This is an issue with you simply using the wrong code to begin with. You should not be using `std::getline()` with non-textual data to begin with. If your goal is to make a copy of a file, then use `std::ifstream::read()` and `std::ofstream::write()` instead. Or better, use facilities that are specifically designed to copy files, like [`std::filesystem::copy_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) or equivalent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the heads-up. Can you suggest some alternatives to std::getline() for non-textual data? And no my goal is not to copy the file.

Comment: @JanglunGuang What is your *actual* goal then? I already gave you alternatives you should be using - `std::ifstream::read()` and `std::ofstream::write()`.